# Installing packages fails

Tags: r, installation

When trying to install packages like ndl, minqa, RcppEigen, lme4 and others I get the following error:

```
    install.packages("RcppEigen")
Installing package into ‘/home/matias/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
probando la URL 'http://cran.at.r-project.org/src/contrib/RcppEigen_0.3.2.0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1251504 bytes (1.2 Mb)
URL abierta
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘RcppEigen’ ...
** package ‘RcppEigen’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/matias/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c RcppEigen.cpp -o RcppEigen.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/matias/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
g++ -shared -o RcppEigen.so RcppEigen.o fastLm.o Note: no visible binding for global variable '.Data' Note: no visible binding for global variable '.Data' -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
g++: error: Note:: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: no: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: visible: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: binding: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: for: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: global: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: variable: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: '.Data': No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: Note:: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: no: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: visible: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: binding: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: for: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: global: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: variable: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: '.Data': No existe el archivo o el directorio
make: *** [RcppEigen.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/home/matias/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RcppEigen’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpzLOC7E/downloaded_packages’
Mensajes de aviso perdidos
In install.packages("RcppEigen") :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried reinstalling R with:

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge r-base r-base-dev r-base-core
 sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

And I removed everything in the R folder, but the problem persists. What can I try next?

Comment: Can you show the exact code that generated this output? And make sure that this still occurs inside a clean R session.

Comment: I just edited it to include the full output. And yes, I've tried it many times in clean R sessions. As I said, same happens with ndl, lme4 and others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am far from an R expert, but I had a similar problem installing minqa, and it was due to a welcome message in my ~/.Rprofile file. It turns out that (for reasons unknown to me) whatever directs the C++ compilation of minqa seems to pipe stdout directly to g++, which is the C++ compiler.

You can see this in your error message:

```
g++: error: Note:: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: no: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: visible: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: binding: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: for: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: global: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: variable: No existe el archivo o el directorio
g++: error: '.Data': No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

Something is producing the message "Note: no visible binding for global variable '.Data'" which is being passed directly to g++. If you can suppress this warning message somehow, my guess is that minqa will then compile happily.

Edit: I just realized that you solved the problem by re-installing Ubuntu. Oh well.

Comment: This is also was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 7):

That looks extremely fscked up.

Now, I develop/maintain these on Ubuntu, so you have a pretty high chance of getting it to work unless you somehow blow up your system.

Try something simpler first.  In R, please do:

```
 R> library(Rcpp)
 R> evalCpp("2+2")
```

Do you get the answer we'd expect?  If not, you are not set up for compiling. Install the `r-base-dev` package as a start.

If everthing else fails, use the prebuild packges which I maintain for lme4, RcppEigen, Rcpp, ...

Comment: Output is: library(Rcpp)
Note: no visible binding for global variable '.Data' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable '.Data' 
> evalCpp("2+2")
[1] 4

Comment: Start by reinstalling Rcpp.

Comment: That one actually installs but throws the warning: Note: no visible binding for global variable '.Data' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable '.->pointer' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable '.Data' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable '.->cpp_class' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable '.->read_only' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable '.->class_pointer' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable '.->docstring' 
[...]

Comment: I can only assure you that your system is broken. I do not know how you broke it, and I cannot tell from these error messages how to unbreak it. Sorry.

Comment: Is there a chance that upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 will fix it or should I just do a clean install?

Comment: Install Rcpp from source. 13.10 has a package that was current when 13.10 was finalized, ie last summer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47978/discussion-between-matias-guzman-naranjo-and-dirk-eddelbuettel)

Comment: No, sorry, I cannot look after every user one-by-one. Try the mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by reinstalling ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it is impossible to say. However these errors can appear for packages that are now deprecated with new R versions. Try:

```
install.packages("ndl")
```

Also insure those are, in fact, the names of the packages and not just functions they provide...

Comment: I have done that. The same happens with lme4 and RcppEigen and others. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

In your .Rprofile file, remove the first line that says : "cat(".Rprofile: Setting cran repositoryn")". This will solve the problem. You can do it by:

```
sudo gedit ~/.Rprofile
```

and removing the first line

Answer (score -1):

Just in case somebody comes across a similar related error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Running'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'R'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'version'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '3.2.0'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '(2015-04-16)'
clang: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Full'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'of'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Ingredients'
make: *** [minqa.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minqa’
```

This is due to including a custom start-up message in `~/.Rprofile`:

```
.First <- function(){
        cat('\nRunning', R.Version()$version.string, '-', R.Version()$nickname, "\n\n") 
}
```

Temporarily removing `~/.Rprofile` causes `minqa` to compile successfully.

Comment: This answer is the same as that of @Kevinismus